# Overriding enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have a set of enum

```
public enum enums
{
    enum1,
    enum2,
    enum3,
    enum4,
    enum5
}
```

and in a another class I want to have two objects:

```
var object1 = new enums();//Here I want an enum of enum1,enum2
var object2 = new enums();//Here I want an enum of enum3,enum4,enum5
```

is there anyone with an idea on how I can do this?

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341

Comment: Could you please explain why you want a single enum, but want to use only half of it?

Comment: Do you want the objects to only be able to hold those values (restriction) or do you want them to contain all the indicated values at once? There's a difference, of which the first cannot be accomplished in C#

Comment: What does this have to do with overriding? And why are people voting to close as "not constructive" instead of "not a real question"?

Comment: Subject was overriding as I thought I will be doing something with new blabl(){....,....,....}; not contructive is their opinion as I faced this and wasn't sure which way to go. and not a real question, maybe to you, but to me it was a question. And by the way why are u bothered answering ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Flags` Attribute and you can assign more values:

```
[Flags]
public enum enums
{
    enum1 = 1,
    enum2 = 2,
    enum3 = 4,
    enum4 = 8,
    enum5 = 16
}
```

here is good post explaining how to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8480/2043144

More edits:

then your code should look like that:

```
enums object1 = enums.enum1 | enums.enum2;
enums object2 = enums.enum3 | enums.enum4 | enums.enum5;
```

to check wether your `object1` contains given flag:

```
if ((object1 & enums.enum1) == enums.enum1) 
{
    //object1 contains enums.enum1 flag
}
```

Comment: You need to use the bitwise OR operator. `var object2 = enum3 | enum4 | enum5;`

Comment: from .NET 4.0 onwards you can also use `Enum.HasFlag()` method instead of bitwise AND operator.

Comment: @alexw it is only supproted in .NET 4 and higher and no way to tell which one OP uses.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question, because there's no limitation for `object2` to use `object2`.